# How can I streamline insertion of LaTeX-math-mode symbols in AUCTeX?

Tags: math-mode, emacs, auctex

In AUCTeX, you can enable a minor mode called `LaTeX-math-mode` that instructs the prefix character `` ` `` to insert various common macros.
For example, `` ` t `` inserts `\tau@` when you are in a math environment (where `@` is where point is left).

This is wonderful when you are in a math environment already.
However, I often refer to these symbols in the running text, and just doing the same `` ` t `` inserts just `\tau{}@` in text mode.

How can I instruct AUCTeX to, when in text mode, *enter* math mode like so: `` ` t `` yields `$\tau$@`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Of course AUCTeX is already able to do this out of the box!  From the description of `LaTeX-math-mode` (<kbd>C-h f</kbd> `LaTeX-math-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd>):

> Easy insertion of LaTeX math symbols.  If you give a prefix argument,
>   the symbols will be surrounded by dollar signs.

Thus, <kbd>C-u ` t</kbd> inserts

```
$\tau$
```

If you want to automatically wrap dollars around the symbol when in text mode without the prefix argument, add this to your `.emacs`:

```lisp
(add-hook
 'LaTeX-mode-hook
 (lambda ()
   (let ((math (reverse (append LaTeX-math-list LaTeX-math-default))))
     (while math
       (let ((entry (car math))
         value)
     (setq math (cdr math))
     (if (listp (cdr entry))
         (setq value (nth 1 entry))
       (setq value (cdr entry)))
     (if (stringp value)
         (fset (intern (concat "LaTeX-math-" value))
           (list 'lambda (list 'arg) (list 'interactive "*P")
             (list 'LaTeX-math-insert value
                   '(null (texmathp)))))))))))
```

This redefines all `LaTeX-math-*` functions defined inside `LaTeX-math-initialize`, in `latex.el`.

Comment: This... this is cool.  I can survive without it, but is there any way to add this prefix argument automatically depending on whether or not we are in math mode?

Comment: @SeanAllred see the updated answer `:-)`.

Comment: This should be the default behaviour. Can you do the same with LaTeX-math-cal? It has the same problem. Ideally, I would like to press ` c (letter) and have \mathcal{letter} written with or without dollar dollar signs depending on whether or not we are in math mode.

Comment: I guess I'll just recomment to call your attention, I tried fixing this by myself but I couldn't do it :(