# How can I streamline insertion of math fonts in AucTeX?

Tags: emacs, auctex

This is essentially a modified question of [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148563/how-can-i-streamline-insertion-of-latex-math-mode-symbols-in-auctex) but with math fonts instead.

What I want is an AucTex command to add to my `.emacs` to do the following:

If I'm outside a math environment like `equation` or outside a pair of dollar signs `$`, If I press `` `1 C ``, `$\mathbb{C}$@` is inserted in the buffer where `@` denotes the position of the cursor.
However, if I'm inside a math environment or inside a a pair of dollar signs, only `\mathbb{C}@` is inserted.
I want `` `2 C `` to do the same as `` `1 C `` but with `\mathcal` instead.
The insertion of math fonts is very common, so this would save a bit of time.
I tried modifying the answer of @[giordano](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/31416/giordano) but I couldn't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be simpler than I thought.
To get the desired effect with `\mathcal`, just add the following to `.emacs`

```
(defun my-LaTeX-math-cal (char dollar)
  (interactive "*c\nP")
  (if (texmathp)
      (LaTeX-math-cal char dollar)
    (LaTeX-math-cal char t))
    )
```

and then bind `my-LaTeX-math-cal` to whatever shortcut. Similar things can be done for `\mathbb` and `\mathfrak`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the font specifier facility provided by AUCTeX: When you're in math mode and you press <kbd>C-c C-f C-a</kbd>, it inserts `\mathcal{@}` and if you mark a portion of text, say `C`, and hit the keystroke, it inserts `\mathcal{C@}` (`@` donates the cursor position).  You get the same thing for `\mathbb` by hitting <kbd>C-c C-f C-b</kbd>.  The keystrokes are stored in `LaTeX-font-list` which is pre-defined like this:

```el
(defcustom LaTeX-font-list
  '((?\C-a ""              ""  "\\mathcal{"    "}")
    (?\C-b "\\textbf{"     "}" "\\mathbf{"     "}")
    (?\C-c "\\textsc{"     "}")
    (?\C-e "\\emph{"       "}")
    (?\C-f "\\textsf{"     "}" "\\mathsf{"     "}")
    (?\C-i "\\textit{"     "}" "\\mathit{"     "}")
    (?\C-l "\\textulc{"    "}")
    (?\C-m "\\textmd{"     "}")
    (?\C-n "\\textnormal{" "}" "\\mathnormal{" "}")
    (?\C-r "\\textrm{"     "}" "\\mathrm{"     "}")
    (?\C-s "\\textsl{"     "}" "\\mathbb{"     "}")
    (?\C-t "\\texttt{"     "}" "\\mathtt{"     "}")
    (?\C-u "\\textup{"     "}")
    (?\C-w "\\textsw{"     "}")
    (?\C-d "" "" t))
  "Font commands used with LaTeX2e.  See `TeX-font-list'.")
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I've asked but it's close. I think I should try to modify that TeX-font-list and/or LaTeX-font-list, right?